# how to pass value using modal.show

Tags: jquery-ui

Im trying to use pass my `car` value to another function, which i have no idea how. i tried to place the whole function `btn-info-add` into `.span8`. But this it will execute twice on the 2nd time.

```
$(".span8").on("click", "table #trID", function() {
   var car = ($(this).closest("tr").children("td").eq(1).html());
   $('#myModal1').modal('show');
});

$("#btn-info-add").click(function() //button inside the modal
    selectCourse(car); //execute ajax
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var car; //car must be declared out of your function to be available for both functions
$(".span8").on("click", "table #trID", function() {
car = ($(this).closest("tr").children("td").eq(1).html());
$('#myModal1').modal('show');
});
$("#btn-info-add").click(function() //button inside the modal
selectCourse(car); //execute ajax
});
```

Comment: yes i know this method, but i have 10 over function, i scare it might have bug.

Comment: i mean if i using the same variable for all the function. which i have already done, nevertheless i still think i should follow this method thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hidden element inside your dialog (`input` would be great) and assign it your desire value.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
  <input id="carvalue" type="hidden" value=""/>
</div>
```

Note that I created an `input` element (hidden, of course) which is going to store the value that I want to access later. After that, you can modify your code like this:

```
$(".span8").on("click", "table #trID", function() {
   var car = ($(this).closest("tr").children("td").eq(1).html());
   $("#carvalue").val(car);  // Store value into hidden input
   $('#myModal1').modal('show');
});

$("#btn-info-add").click(function() //button inside the modal
    var car = $("#carvalue").val(); // retrieve value from input hidden
    if(car != ""){
       selectCourse(car); 
    }
});
```

This technique is commonly used in forms to pass additional information on AJAX calls. Your user will not notice its presence and you can keep working. Happy coding!

**EDIT:**

JQuery has a method called [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to store information into JQuery elements. So your values are going to be stored on the element itself. Your code will look like this:

```
$(".span8").on("click", "table #trID", function() {
   var car = ($(this).closest("tr").children("td").eq(1).html());
   jQuery.data("#btn-info-add", "car", car);   // store data inside jQuery element
   $('#myModal1').modal('show');
});

$("#btn-info-add").click(function() //button inside the modal
    selectCourse(jQuery.data("#btn-info-add", "car")); //execute ajax
});
```

I hope it helps you. Happy coding!

Comment: i thought of using .text, but user might be able to change html data. so i was no able to use for my school work.

Comment: @user2863217 If this worked for you, accept it as a valid answer to help people with your problem :)